# How to override the H1 element from module?

Tags: 7

I am trying to override the h1 element on a node view for a content type. I do not want to change the meta tags or anything else. Any tips how I could achieve this?

I have been trying something like this, but it has no effect

```
function xxx_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
    dpm($vars);
    if ($vars["type"] == 'mycontenttype') {
        $custom_title = $vars["title"] . " TESTING";
        $vars['title'] = $custom_title;
        dpm($vars);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sample code that will overwrite the title page of Drupal, you have to locate within the `template.php` file of the active theme Drupal website.

```
function YOUR_THEME_NAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $node = menu_get_object();
  if (isset($node->nid) && $node->type == 'your-content-type-name') {
    $custom_title= "My custom title on node: ". $node->title;
    $vars['title'] = $custom_title;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok thx, but wouldn't a theme update with drush override the theme's template.php file? I would like to do this from a custom module.

Comment: yes you can use it just replace function YOUR_THEME_NAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) with your module